# django oauth toolkit user registration

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, registration

I implemented django oauth toolkit to my project so I can handle to login a user and get the access token, but I have no idea how to register a user and then create a new access token.
Can anybody help me creating the registration view?

client type: confidential

grant type: password

serializers.py

```
class UserRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    confirm_password = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = user_models.User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password',
            'confirm_password',
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'confirm_password': {'read_only': True}
        }

    def validate(self, data):
        try:
            user = user_models.User.objects.filter(
                username=data.get('username'))
            if user.exists():
                raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Username already exists'))
        except user_models.User.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        if not data.get('password') or not data.get('confirm_password'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Empty password'))

        if data.get('password') != data.get('confirm_password'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Password mismatch'))

        return data
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49153742/9137276) answers your question