# How to register a normal user using django oAuth toolkit

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-oauth-toolkit

I am using the Django-Oauth-toolkit in my web app development.In that i can able to create new application using django admin panel and created the new admin users.And i can able to login that newly created admin users and able to get the token.But my problem is, i can able to register the user using my model and user is created in my db.But when i try to login with created user and try to get token with o/token with oauth grand type, then i am not getting token and getting invalid credentials response.But super user credentials login and token generation is working fine.And in django admin panel, super users are listed under 'Authetication and authorization' and normal users are listed under Django app.So please help me how to generate the tokens for users which are registered in django app.Or how to create the super users from django app.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found a solution to your issue. I was facing the same problem, and stumble on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49153742/15468138).

You should check it out.

On the other hand you should use django's `createsuperuser` command to add users, so that they are also registered in your django oauth toolkit application.